# Did the Foursquare API just change without notice? Ratings not returning from Explore endpoint

Tags: foursquare

The app we're developing just stopped working as intended. Upon further digging we noticed that the rating is no longer being return on the venue object from the Explore endpoint. Does anyone know if this is an intentional change (without notice) from the Foursquare team or if it's somehow an error that will be corrected?

Comment: Hey there! We're currently investigating an issue related to missing ratings from explore results. However, this has always been an optional field that's not guaranteed in all [responses](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue) anyway—please make sure you have appropriate logic to handle going forward!

Comment: @octopi thanks for the reply. I realize that the reviews are not always guaranteed but they haven't been in the results in more than 2 days now. Also, is there a reason why they aren't always included? Is that something that will change in the future?